# Hide first slide on Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm trying to hide first slide (a bit of a hack for something) of my slick slider. And got no luck at all so far. Here is my html code for it

```
<div class="slidewrap" >
     <div class="sitem" id="hidethisslide">
     </div>
     <div class="sitem">
     </div>
     <div class="sitem">
     </div>
</div>
```

And here is my jquery for it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slidewrap').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: false,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    arrows:true
  });
$('.slidewrap').slick('slickRemove','#hidethisslide');
});
```

Slider works perfectly fine, and there are no errors in the console. But first slide is still there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is .upsellwrap class in dom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$('.upsellwrap').slick('slickRemove','#hidethisslide');
```

to

```
$('.slidewrap').slick('slickRemove',0);
```

Comment: @StackSlave
Could you make the 'slickRemove' work with a number array? Or a range?
This doesn't work but something like:

$('.slidewrap').slick('slickRemove',[0,1]); 
or 
=>2